# Align text to right in button in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have button with text:

```
Button(
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    contentColor = colors.primary,
                ),
                elevation = null,
                onClick = {},
                border = BorderStroke(0.dp, Color.Transparent),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.name),
                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Right
                )
            }
```

Now text in button is centered. How can I move this text to right/end in this button. `textAlign = TextAlign.Right` not working.

Answer (score 8):

You have to specify `width` for `Button` and `Text`.

```
Button(
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        contentColor = colors.primary,
    ),
    elevation = null,
    onClick = {},
    border = BorderStroke(0.dp, Color.Transparent),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.name),
        fontSize = 12.sp,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Right,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
}
```

I have given full width for `Button`

```
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
```

Also let your `Text` to occupy that parent `width`.

```
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
```

Comment: Thanks - this should be marked as the solution. Omitting `fillMaxWidth()` on the `Text` is an easy mistake to make.